# cocos2d-x 2.1.4 where is spriteWithTexture in version 2.1.4?

Tags: cocos2d-x

Im learning the new version of cocos2d-x 2.1.4
im porting cocos2d to x version , i want to port this section :

```
spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode 
batchNodeWithFile:"foo.gif"];
player = [CCSprite spriteWithBatchNode:spriteSheet
rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 56)];
```

to :

```
spritSheet = CCSpriteBatchNode::create("foo.gif");
player = CCSprite::??? which function here ???();
```

reading here :  http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2dx/wiki/API_Change_List_from_v1x_to_2x?version=2

> CCSprite::spriteWithBatchNode(...) is removed, please use: sprite =
>   CCSprite::spriteWithTexture(batchNode->getTexture(), CCRect*);
>   batchNode->addChild(sprite); instead

but there is no spriteWithTexture in CCSprite 
what is replacement ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well You can use this. They have modified the function calls

```
CCSprite *pSprite = CCSprite::createWithTexture(pTexture, rect);
```

Answer (score 0):

I havent used it yet the latest cocos, but given the error it seems that you just need to do something like:

```
player = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:[spriteSheet getTexture];
[spriteSheet addChild:player]
```

they just removed the spriteWithBatchNode init, but you can easly get the texture from a batchnode with getTexture